# Подружить USB HID устройство с PHP

Tags: windows, php, usb

Есть очень странная (слегка извращенная) задача.
Необходимо подружить `USB HID` устройство (редкий ридер для RFID карт) с `PHP`. Причем под `Windows`.

За несколько часов поисков самое полезное, что я нашел, - класс `PHP Serial`, который позволяет работать с `COM` (и вроде бы как с `USB`, но только под `Linux`).

Если кто знает, подскажите, РЕАЛЬНО ли, и если "да" — дайте хотя бы направление поиска...

Comment: Я думаю, что реально, если на С написать свой модуль.

Answer (score 3):

> Если кто знает - подскажите, РЕАЛЬНО
> ли и если да — хотя бы направление
> поиска...

Ответ прежде всего зависит от поставленных вами целей.
Так как PHP является интерпретируемым, серверным языком, в нем отсутствует нативная возможность управления железом.
Любые взаимодействия производятся либо через расширение **[Direct IO](http://pecl.php.net/package/dio)**, либо через вызов консольных утилит, подобно следующему `exec('df');`
Так что в вашем случае решение будет скомбинированным.

Если к вашему девайсу прилагается ПО с консольным интерефейсом, это могло бы облегчить вам задачу.